# Spring Integration : get poll expression from database

Tags: ftp, spring-integration, poller

I have an FTP message source and I want to enable the user to configure the poll frequency through an application.

This is the current configuration of the Inbound channel adapter

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "fromSmartpath", poller = @Poller(cron = "0 15 8 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT"))
public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() throws SftpException {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
            sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
    source.setLocalDirectory(new File(Constants.LOCAL_REPOSITORY_PATH));
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    source.setLocalFilter(new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metaDataStore(), "metastore"));
    return source;
}
```

My goal is to retrieve the cron expression from the database. Is There a way to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cron expression ends up in the `CronTrigger`. You can develop some service which SELECT an expression from DB in its `afterPropertiesSet()` and returns it via getter.
Then you declare a `@Bean` for the `CronTrigger` and call that getter from the service during its definition.

The `@Poller` on the `@InboundChannelAdapter` has a `trigger` option to refer to the existing bean.

Comment: Thank you for the response. @Polller indeed has a trigger option but it accepts a string not a bean. That string has to be a constant, so the possibility to define a method that gets the cron expression from the DB wont work either

Comment: What? the ` trigger` option is a bean reference. Means bean name. Fully not sure what is not clear for you. You create a `@Bean` for the `CronTrigger` and use its name in that option. Of course annotations can't reference to objects. That's not how they work...

Comment: Ok That's embarrassing (execuse my newbieness). That worked for me. Another question if you may, how can I reload the InboundChannelAdapter 
 to take the new cron value when the user changes the cron expression in the DB

Comment: You can achieve that only with the custom trigger implementation